# Android NFC in Embarcadero XE5

Tags: android, delphi, nfc, delphi-xe5

Trying to get NFC to work on Android in Embarcadero XE5.
Started with the following: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=97574
which seem to be working. Now would like to register callback for the NFC Intent

Java approach:

```
1. Register current activity as a listener
...
2. Receive Intent
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = NfcUtils.getNdefMessages(intent);
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/

Delphi approach (as I would imagine):

```
1. Define methods available in Java interface
```

Source: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=634212

```
Question:
How do I register a listener for NFC intent messages and 
how do I eventually get messages?
```

My guess would be to call `enableForegroundDispatch` method. Define it like:

```
procedure enableForegroundDispatch; cddcl;
```

to call it from Android API

But since I have never done this before, I do not know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : ***Seems I have missed a tag and the OP does not ask for Java code. Leaving this anyway for future reference***

Your guess is correct, although it might be possible to define the intents you want to listen for in the AndroidManifest.xml, foreground dispatch really puts your app in the **front**, giving you the ability to capture ***all*** launched NFC intents.

The way it is described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) gives you a clue.

I assume you're familiar with the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) of the Android Activities, Intent Dispatching and such.

---

#### Structure

Using the following structure, you'd have 4 fields :

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] mIntentFilters;
private String[][] mTechLists;
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
```

In the `onCreate` you'd get :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    mIntentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)};
    mTechLists = new String[][]{new String[]{Ndef.class.getName()},
                new String[]{NdefFormatable.class.getName()}};
}
```

This ***does*** not actually enable the Foreground Dispatch yet, it is just the preparation.
The application would receive the Ndef and NdefFormatable [technologies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#tech-disc)
Why do we subscribe for ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED ?

The order in which Android tries to handle the intent is as such :

1. ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
2. ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED
3. ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED

So we make sure our app is the first to be looked at by Android.

---

#### Enable FGD

Put the following line of code in the `onResume` method :

```
if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, mIntentFilters, mTechLists);
    }
```

Why is this in the `onResume`? As the docs state : `enableForegroundDispatch() must be called from the main thread and only when the activity is in the foreground (calling in onResume() guarantees this)`

This should enable your app to receive the intent, of course, when actually running.
If you want to receive intents while not running, you'd have to go to the AndroidManifest.